# Force Zoom-Level/DPI-Scale with CSS, Header-Tag or JavaScript

Tags: css, zooming, dpi

We have a strange issue here. We have a website wich worked nice since a few years. A couple of months ago, Firefox startet to scale the page depending on the user DPI-settings on his operating system.

The problem is, by default the DPI scale is set to 125% (in our country) in Windows 7 and every visitor using Firefox sees the page scaled. Howevery, Internet Explorer and Safari now doing the same, and I guess chrome will follow.

The tricky part is: When I open the page I see the correct layout. If I check the zoom level of the browser it tells me 100% - When I am opening the same page with firefox or Internet explorer, everything is scaled up (zoomed in) by 25%. If i check the zoom level in the browser settings, it says 100%. If I zoom out twice (to 80%) I see the original layout.

Is there an easy way to set the default dpi scale / zoom level by CSS, JavaScript or maybe a header tag?

Here are some screenshots to explain my issue a bit.

[image: The "right" layout]
This is the right layout as used to over the past years. The page is centered and on the left and right side is a bit of the background

[image: the "zoomed" in]
On Firefox, IE and Safari the same page on the same computer looks like this. It is zoomed in, you don't see the background and you see a bit less of the total content.

So now my question: what can I do, to make the same page look the same way on different computers as it comes to the scaling. I know several things always differ but the scale should be the same.

Edit:

Always scaling the page with transform: scale(.75); transfor-origin: 100%; 0; is not always suitable, because if a user with 100% DPI setting visits the page, everything is minimized for him. I can not always scale the page. I need to somehow identify if the user has set his operating system to 100% or 125% DPI scaling.

Edit:

Yes there is an option to determine the setted scale rate. At least for my setup this works by now. I add a screenshot with two browsers opened on the same machine (chrome top, firefox bottom) to see the difference (and the problem which seriously needs to get fixed by someone)

[image: device pixel ratio differnce from browser to browser on the same machine<code>enter code here</code>]

Comment: Wel I guess you could scale the body to always fit with `width:100vw` and then using the `%` to scale elements to always get the browser to look the same to every one. But I guess that's  a lot of work on an already coded site.

Comment: @Persijn Yes this is true, it would be a lot of work. I praise the lord when we finally decide to emigrate to a new shop system and drop this self made demon to where it belongs, the deepest part of hell -_-

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995914/catch-browsers-zoom-event-in-javascript
Sorry its not possible

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the browser dpi level with javascript and zoom the page contents accordingly with css(if needed).

```
if(window.devicePixelRatio == 1 )
  $("body").addClass("zoom2x")
```

Where zoom2x is a css class.

```
.zoom2x{
      zoom: 200%; /* all browsers */
     -moz-transform: scale(2);  /* Firefox */
}
```

You may crosscheck your current dpi setting [here](https://www.infobyip.com/detectmonitordpi.php) and verify results.

Comment: thank you this worked. I edited my question and added a screenshot

Comment: How should we handle multiple different DPI settings? There's no guarantee that the user's DPI is 125% only and not something else.

Comment: @posfan12 Do you mean multiple DPI settings across different browsers? or across different tabs of the same browser?

Comment: No, I mean Person A has 125%, Person B has 150%, etc.

Answer (score -1):

There doesn't seem to be a code fix for this, but it can be fixed by changing your browser settings. See links below:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/962979 
[Stop Firefox DPI Scaling (when Windows setting is at 125%)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23099849/stop-firefox-dpi-scaling-when-windows-setting-is-at-125)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can not accept this solution because I need something what works on the users computer, not on mine. You can not expect that a user has to change settings because some browser vendors went crazy by changing politics in a non redundant way. If every browser would treat this problem the same way, I could adapt to it. Also every serious browser would implement some kind of fallback before the change, a flag or something. But the way Mozilla went is far then fair. Change fundamental scaling functions without an explanation and ignoring the hundrets ofusercomplaints