# Browser is scaling page to 125%

Tags: html, css, opera

I have a display with resolution 2560x1440. I have noticed that web page I am working on is scaled to 125%. So if border is set to 4px - it has 5px on the screen. It happens in Opera, Chrome, Firefox, but not in Edge.

I assume it is related to Windows font size settings (which is set to 125% on my computer).

How to disable this feature using CSS code (or in `meta` tag in `head`?) or at least in browser settings?

Sample code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- it does not change anything -->
        <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width: 10px; height: 10px; background-color: red;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Results:

[image: Browser scaling]

Comment: If possible, create working snippet or provide your webpage link.

Comment: Can you just use your browser's scaling (eg, control-minus twice) to reduce the browser's content display to 80% on that site, and reduce the 125% scale back to 100%?  It's quick and dirty solution, but if all you want is to see that one site in its native resolution, it might work.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> did you inculde this meta tag?

Comment: @RobWilkins: thanks for advice, I will use it, I hope it will not produce any rounding errors.

Comment: @SahilDhir: yes, it does not change anything (firefox, opera)

Comment: @AbhishekPandey: done

Comment: Does your device have a dppx greater then 1?

Comment: If 125 % is that, what your user want to see, you shouldn't force him to another resolution. Think of 80 years old people, that wear extra fat glasses ;)

Comment: @MrLister: Sorry, I don't understand. It is DELL U2515H. Specs says it has 117 dpi. As I know from some WPF tutorials, Windows uses 96 dpi as base (?). So 96/117 = ~1.21. Now I have tested scaling ratio again with 100x100 pixels square, and it draws 120x120 square. So I made mistake in title, it is really 120% not 125%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found an answer.

**For Firefox:**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24958483/6552578

**Chrome:**
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/_jmREHlt3ZE

Solution - need to edit desktop link to Chrome like that:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"  /force-device-scale-factor=1
```