# How to query the current zoom level with CSS

Tags: css, media-queries

Is it possible to query the browser zoom in CSS?

We have multiple Windows devices with active "display scaling on high DPI devices" options. It is not possible for us to disable the 125 percent default zoom on all devices.

A third party wants us to manipulate some parts of the website if the zoom is exactly at 125 percent.

We have already tried several [min-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27154096/7177728) media queries but they also affected the MacBook Pro (retina).

Comment: You can use media queries to append styles if a condition like the viewport width or the device pixel ratio matches a predefined value. I would call this a query ;-)

Comment: Yeah but I don't think they have yet included zooming in media queries - there were proposals, but nothing formal was made:https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/WG/wiki/Proposals/Zoom_feature_for_media_queries