# DPI or scaling with Firefox on Windows

Tags: css, windows, google-chrome, firefox, dpi

A customer of mine complained about some "artifacts" on his website that appeared on his HP notebook with Firefox (Chrome does not show any problem). He is using Windows 10 and he said his Windows is scaled at 125% by default and his Chrome/Firefox are with 100% view mode.

So I tried that on my Lenovo notebook, simulate the conditions the customer said and I didnt see the problem. Then I tried on a Dell notebook and the artifacts happened exactly as the customer said. The HTML code is pretty simple:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-size: cover; background-position: center center; background-image: url(&quot;https://www.sitepor500.com.br/imagens/fundo3.jpg&quot;);"></div>

<div style="position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px; width:100%; height:100%; background:url(https://www.sitepor500.com.br/imagens/vegas-04.png) top left repeat; background-attachment:fixed;"></div>
```

You can see this code live at http://quemfazsite.com.br/temp/teste.php on your computer.

On my Chrome I see this:

[image]

On my Firefox I see this:

[image]

You can see the artifacts on the right side? So, is there a CSS property I can use to tell browsers to work as expected and avoid those artifacts?

Comment: avoid those horizontal lines in the background.

Comment: @DanielA.White that repeated pattern is just a sample, the website is much more complex and it needs to use repeated pattern to look good, it has a slideshow at the bottom of the pattern.

Comment: Rather than tile a x2 pixel to achieve the interlacing effect, have you considered just using a larger tile.  Like a 10x10 or 100x100 where every row alternates between black line and transparent line?

Comment: Also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23099849/stop-firefox-dpi-scaling-when-windows-setting-is-at-125